# How to perform cleanup after custom Gtk widget is destroyed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have a custom Gtk widget like `MyWidget` defined in the code example below:

```
import gc
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MyWidget(Gtk.Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = 5

    def __del__(self):
        print('__del__   :', self, getattr(self, 'x', None))

    def do_destroy(self):
        print('do_destroy:', self, getattr(self, 'x', None))
        # clean up self.x


widget = MyWidget()

del widget
gc.collect()
```

After the widget is destroyed, I need to do some cleanup (my custom widget is a button that opens a dialog window, after my button is destroyed, I would like to destroy the dialog window it created if it still exists, [like FileChooserButton](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/bb56b4ef5d975fff91e7caa39e058d02fd7373bb/gtk/gtkfilechooserbutton.c#L1051)).

My problem is, running the code above, I get the output:

```
__del__   : <__main__.MyWidget object at 0x105340678 (__main__+MyWidget at 0x7fc1bc0bc340)> 5
do_destroy: <__main__.MyWidget object at 0x1053406c0 (__main__+MyWidget at 0x7fc1bc0bc340)> None
__del__   : <__main__.MyWidget object at 0x1053406c0 (__main__+MyWidget at 0x7fc1bc0bc340)> None
```

My understanding is that in PyGObject, all Python objects are just wrappers for the underlying GObject. So my reasoning for the above output is this. The `widget` wrapper is about to be garbage collected so it's `__del__()` method is called. After the `widget` wrapper is garbage collected, it seems like the underlying widget is then prepared to be destroyed as the `do_destroy()` method is then called. But `do_destroy()` is called with `self` set to a new wrapper object different to the original `widget` object, and `self.x` no longer exists. Then the new wrapper's `__del__()` is called.

My question is, where should I put the '`self.x` clean up logic', and also if anyone knows, how does PyGObject create new wrapper objects (it does not seem to invoke `__new__()` or `__init__()`)?

Another problem with me putting the clean up logic in `do_destroy()` is that `do_destroy()` seems to be invoked every time the widget's `destroy()` method is called, which can be done multiple times.